# wordpress have to click on link twice to go to external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, escaping

I am editing the following code for my menu on a single page wordpress site. there is a the problem is solved if i remove all of this code but it provides a nice scrolling effect when left in. i commented out the `event.preventDefault()` and this allows the external links to work when clicked on twice which is not desirable. is there any way i can maybe escape the external link from this code. only links in this menu are affected by this but the link does have to remain in the same menu.

```
// SCROLL TO
$('#main-menu-top a,ul.slicknav_nav li a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();

    console.log($('#main-menu-top a,ul.slicknav_nav li a'));

    //event.preventDefault();

        if($(this).hasClass('active'))
            return;

        $('#main-menu-top a').removeClass('active').css('border-bottom-color', 'none');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if(this.hash == "#home")
            $.scrollTo(0,800);
        else
            $.scrollTo( this.hash, 800, {offset:-$(".sticky-wrapper").height()});

        var bgcolor = $(this.hash).find('span.line-title').css('backgroundColor');
        $(this).css('border-bottom-color', bgcolor);

        $('.slicknav_nav').hide('normal', function() {
            $(this).addClass('slicknav_hidden');
        });
        $('a.slicknav_btn').removeClass('slicknav_open').addClass('slicknav_collapsed');

        return false;

});
```

Comment: Not sure about this code, however just wanted mention what if you comment the last line i.e.  return false; it is preventing the click going to parent elements. Could this be the reason?

Comment: that worked to  a certain extent @Mohsin. but the scrolling effect jumps around before arriving at the desired location.

Comment: Awesome :-) Happy to hear!

Comment: I have added it to answer you may mark that accepted answer to mark question resolved.  Thanks

Comment: @Mohsin Thanks For your input but on a second look sacrifice the scrolling effect looks better than the flash i am getting by removing the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the last line return false;

It might be preventing click take place.

Adding this answer here for future reference.